# Passing Data(String) from Child View Controller to Parent VC using Segues

Tags: objective-c, ios

Passing Data(String) from Child View Controller to Parent VC using Segues.
Can Someone suggest me the Fastest and easiest way  (in Storyboarding),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this blog it is explain every thing u need to know  :)

http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ActionsViewController *vc =[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"-----"];
vc.Title =[namesarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//where Title variable at next view class
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement
`prepareForSegue:sender:`
where you have access to the `destinationViewController`.